# How can I make a photo high resolution without changing its size?

Tags: photo-editing

I just want to make my photo look higher resolution at its original size.

Comment: By "size", do you mean number of pixels, file size, size when actually printed or something else?

Comment: …or you mean you want it to look 'sharper', cleaner edges, better focus? Being able to see the original may help.

Comment: With no response after 10 days, I'm closing this question as "needs detail or clarity".

Answer (score 2):

You can use various forms of sharpening to increase the contrast of the recorded details. This will make them more readily visible and increase the appearance of resolution.

Your other choice is to use some form of AI to add details/resolution that is not there already. Using a program like Topaz Gigapixel AI to make the image much larger, and then to return the image to its' original size, will increase both the detail and sharpness... but some of it will be artificial.

Similarly, you could add detail yourself by cloning, copying, drawing, etc,...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Topaz DeNoise AI, it reduces noice and add AI sharpness, take a look here: https://topazlabs.com/tag/topaz-denoise-ai/